# A hyperplane $W$ of a symplectic vector space $V$ is coisotropic.

Tags: solution-verification, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I want to make sure that my proof is correct and see other nice ways how we can show it.

Let $V$ be a symplectic vector space of dimension $2n$ and $W$ is a subspace of $V$ of dimension $2n-1$. We want to show that $W$ is a coisotropic subspace of $V$ i.e. $W^{\omega}\subset W$ where $W^{\omega}=\{v\in V|\omega(v,w)=0\text{ for all }w\in W\}$ with a given symplectic form $\omega$.

Let's take some non-zero vector $v\in V$, and consider a new subspace $W^{\prime}=W\oplus span\{v\}\subset V$. If $W^{\prime}$ is a proper subset of $V$, then we are done. So, it's enough to show that the case $v\notin W$ will gives us a contradiction. But, we will obtain a contradiction by showing that our symplectic form is degenerate since we found a non-zero vector $v\in V$ s.t. $\omega(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in V$.

*Does  it make sense?*

Comment: Why is $W'=W\oplus\operatorname{span}\{v\}$ a subset of $V$?  Remember you selected nonzero $v\in W$ so you are forming the "external" direct sum here.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I took a non-zero $v\in V$ and not in $W$ since I want to show if $v\in W^{\omega}$ then $v\in W$. So, $W\oplus span\{v\}\subset V$.

Comment: No, it still doesn't exclude me choosing $v\in W$ before you form this $W'$.

Comment: Wait a second, we want to show that $W^{\omega}\subset W$ i.e. we want to show that if $v\in W^{\omega}$ then $v\in W$. So, let's take any $v\in W^{\omega}$. Then by definition of $W^{\omega}$, we have that $v\in V$ such that $\omega(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in W$. Right now, I want to show that $v\in W$. So, if $w\in W$, then I am done. If not, then I consider my new space $W^{\prime}$. Where is the flow?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that we have some idea what you're talking about? We have a symplectic vector space $V$ and an arbitrary subspace $W$ of $V$?

Comment: Sure. $W$ is a hyperplane of $V$.